# Use Infura to run a IPFS node in Java Android

Tags: java, android, ipfs

I am trying to connect to an Infura node from Java Android application.
I was following these documents to connect to an infura node.

https://kauri.io/managing-storage-in-a-java-application-with-ipfs/3e8494f4f56f48c4bb77f1f925c6d926/a

https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/java-ipfs-http-client/issues/115

Code:

```
package com.example.javahttp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import io.ipfs.api.IPFS;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    IPFS ipfs ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new MyTask().execute();
    }
    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void , Void, Void > {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            IPFS ipfs = new IPFS("/dnsaddr/ipfs.infura.io/tcp/5001/https");

            try{
                System.out.println("connected");
                System.out.println("id: "+ ipfs.id());
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("not connected"+e);
            }


            return null;
        }


    }


}
```

I am getting this error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: IOException contacting IPFS daemon.
    Trailer: null ipfs method not allowed
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Provide your code of what you have been trying to do..

Comment: @fuzious Code added.

Comment: I have added a suggestion. Refer it and do revert if it works / doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get why there is such an error but when I used a plain java class to connect with it. It was possible ,you may refer here to my repository [blockchain with java](https://github.com/fuzious/blockchain-with-Java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/blockchainInit/IPFS/App.java) to see if you have all the relevant dependencies and you have been doing it properly because I am not familiar with android but I am familiar with web3j.

You can use the below code to connect with an infura node and parse a file to it.

```
import io.ipfs.api.IPFS;
import io.ipfs.api.MerkleNode;
import io.ipfs.api.NamedStreamable;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        IPFS ipfs = new IPFS("/dnsaddr/ipfs.infura.io/tcp/5001/https");
        try {
            NamedStreamable.InputStreamWrapper is = new NamedStreamable.InputStreamWrapper(new FileInputStream());
            MerkleNode response = ipfs.add(is).get(0);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error whilst communicating with the IPFS node", ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: My code is similar to your. the only difference is that I havve included a Asynctask and that's because android gives some mainthread error if I write it in thhe main function.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar then I guess there is some issue related to  then because I was successfully able to host my file.

Comment: @fuzious this solution don't work in 2022, send me the error project id is required... how do this today?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has trouble with this nowadays, the fix to this issue was simply to upgrade to the newest version.

I upgraded from **v1.2.3** to **v1.3.3** and the issue disappeared.

For maven, `pom.xml`:

```xml
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.ipfs</groupId>
      <artifactId>java-ipfs-http-client</artifactId>
      <version>v1.3.3</version>
  </dependency>
```